# Bold on Arial font in sections

Tags: fonts, titlesec, section-titles

I am trying to have bold in the sections and sub sections using Arial font, all I managed is non-bold titles, here is my conde:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Thesis}
\date{July 2020}
\font\myfont=Arial at 28pt
\font\myfontsub=Arial at 17pt
\font\myfontsubsub=Arial at 13pt
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}{\myfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\myfontsub}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\myfontsubsub}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

i am using overleaf.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!Try `\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\myfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}`, &c.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the reply! The code doesn't produce an error , but it does not make the title bold either.

Comment: What happens if you try Arial with `pdflatex` (i.e. without fontspec)?

Comment: @Bernard i tried , it doesn't even appear the sections

Comment: But did you install the `urw-arial` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Arial as your sans-serif font with `fontspec` and use LaTeX formatting commands.  Select the font family wirh `\sffamily`, the bold weight with `\bfseries`, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Thesis}
\date{July 2020}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries\huge}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries\large}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Sub-Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial font sample]

If you want to use specific font sizes, use the `\fontsize` command instead of `\huge`, etc.  Be aware that the point sizes in LaTeX are not exactly the same as the point sizes in Word.

I commonly load my main font with `Scale=1.0` so that it is at its natural size, and set `\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }`, so all other fonts have the same x-height,`but you might or might not want to do that here.